# UICollectionView Contentoffsize

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am working on horizontal table view, and I used `UICollectionView` for this. I want to add sliding system like a ticker. But I am getting error when sliding is done. I want to restart this operation when end items slide all of them.

My codes :

```
-(void)slideBulletin{
    CGPoint newContentOffset = self.kayanBant.contentOffset;
    newContentOffset.x += 1;
    self.kayanBant.contentOffset = newContentOffset;

    if (self.kayanBant.contentOffset.x>(self.kayanBant.contentSize.width-10)) {

    }
}- (void)startUpTicker
```

{

```
__weak DLSDashboardViewController *weakSelf = self;

NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate * dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.%i.%i",now.day,now.month,now.year];

NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@?tarih=%@", EXTERNAL_API_BORSA_ROOT_URL, EXTERNAL_API_POLATLI_API_GET_DAILY_BULLETIN_URL,dateString];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestString]]];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    DLSDashboardViewController *strongSelf = weakSelf;

    if (strongSelf)
    {
        strongSelf.bulletin = [DLSDailyBulletin bulletinFromJson:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:0 error:nil]];
        DLSDailyBulletinItem *item = strongSelf.bulletin.allItems[0];
        if (!item.isFound)
        {
            strongSelf.bulletin = nil;
            strongSelf.notFoundLabel.hidden = NO;
        }
        else
        {
            strongSelf.notFoundLabel.hidden = YES;
        }

        [strongSelf.kayanBant reloadData];


        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.025
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(slideBulletin)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];
        [self.timer fire];




    }

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    DDLogError(@"Failed to get currently bulletin: %@", error);

    DLSDashboardViewController *strongSelf = weakSelf;
    NSLog(@"%@",error);

    if (strongSelf)
    {
        strongSelf.notFoundLabel.hidden = NO;
    }

}];

[operation start];
```

}

And I am getting this error:

```
2014-09-24 10:43:21.170 ****[2948:67320] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException',
    reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 12 beyond bounds [0 .. 11]'
```

Comment: you are increasing index value more than "count-1",index value must be less than "count-1"

Comment: Your crash does not look to be related to the code you posted.  Instead it's being caused by the underlying model/array accessing an element beyond its range - e.g. your model has 12 items and your trying to access the 13th.

Comment: I have 12 items but this changes for example if I have 30 items this error will change.. I want to sliding cells, and when it end start again. I do this change coordinate of x.. I deleted inside if condution... I am searching what write inside of if block?

Comment: The error you are facing can't be generated by the code you posted here. The problem lies some where else. Please have a look to your code from where this slideBulletin function is called.

Comment: I added calling function part..